# i have been trying to implement custom login where i'll be updating the password but db.savechanges isn't working with my code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePassword model)
 {
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
    UserDetail ud = db.UserDetails.FirstOrDefault(s => s.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
     try
     {
       if (ud.Password == model.OldPassword)
       {
        ud.Password = model.NewPassword;
        TryUpdateModel(ud);
        **db.SaveChanges();**
        return RedirectToAction("ChangePasswordSuccess");
        }
        else
        {
         ViewBag.ErrorMsgForPassword = "old password is not correct";
        }
      }
    catch
    {
      return View();   
    }
 }
```

Comment: What do you means 'not working'? Is there exception? Or what? Give us more information.

Comment: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. this is the error i'm getting which i'm not able to understand

Comment: Could you show your UserDetail class?

Comment: public int Id { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter a user Name")]

public string UserName { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter a Password")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter the Date Of Birth")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter a EmailID")]
public string EMail { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is mandatarory")]
public Address Residence { get; set; }
public Address Office { get; set; }

Comment: have solved the problem it was with the complex type in UserDetails class

Comment: if you have found teh answer to your problem and if you think it would help others to then post the answer else if you think that this question is too specific and wont help anybody then delete it

Comment: there was a problem in retrieving the complex types if we can retrieve the complex type then the problem is solved hope that it would help any one with the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while password change the complex types were not loaded so while updating he password db.savechanges() didn't work so if you load the complex types(addresses in this case) the problem is solved